# Fabric failed to download settings Error Domain=FABNetworkError Code=-6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, twitter-fabric

I have implemented Fabric in my app and it always worked properly. Now, when I try to run my app on device I'm getting the following error:

> [Fabric] failed to download settings Error Domain=FABNetworkError
>   Code=-6 "(null)"

On simulator always works properly. Any idea?

Comment: are you behind a proxy ? also try to search for that FABNetworkError Code in your library

Answer (score 7):

As per the [Twitter forum](https://twittercommunity.com/t/fabric-failed-to-download-settings-error-domain-fabnetworkerror-code-6-null/59848), this error message indicates that Fabric has troubles connecting to the server, i.e. no internet connection or one that is very slow / experiences a high package loss rate.

If you're in doubt, try opening a website on the device / emulator.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates an error connecting to the server. In my case it came up after an update, and I just had to uninstall the app completely and reinstall.